# Availability-only not shown on inventory level in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory, quantity, cataloginventory, stock-availability

For my Magento store, **the threshold qty is not considered on inventory level**, although this is set up in the backend.

This is the view with the output of the **QTY** message

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/default.phtml

```
<?php if($this->isMsgVisible()): ?>
    <p class="availability-only">
        <span title="<?php echo $this->__('Only %s left', ($this->getStockQty())) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Only %s left', "<strong>{$this->getStockQty()}</strong>") ?></span>
    </p>
<?php endif ?>
```

This file gets the input out of

> app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Block\Stockqty\Abstract.php

```
public function isMsgVisible()
    {
        return ($this->getStockQty() > 0 && $this->getStockQty() <= $this->getThresholdQty());
    }
```

but it seems that `$this->getStockQty()` is not considering the manually edited inventory qty.